# Did I delete the wrong user folder? Even if I didn't, how can I rename my current one?

Tags: windows-10, system-restore

I just bought a new Windows 10 computer, but after an issue with an update taking away my ability to operate the battery threshold, I did system restore. I named my computer and the account the same things as before when it was done.

However, in the user folder, there was one named with just my name, for now, lets say Jason (I originally had my account name `C:\Users\Jason`; I also named it Jason when I restored it). It had all the old files, including ones that were listed on its desktop folder but weren't actually currently on the desktop. But there was also a new one called `C:\Users\Jason.LAPTOP-8CBAIQSU`. I deleted `C:\Users\Jason` because it took up a ton of storage, but now, my user folder has a name I can't remember in case I need to use it.

How can I fix this? Also, when I deleted it, it claimed there were system files in it, but I deleted even those anyway, and I've not had any problems with the PC (although getting CodeBlocks to work took a while).

Did I delete the right folder?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming user folders can be a pain because of all the different locations where it may be used, so maybe don't do it at all.

I'd do the following:

- Open the start menu.
- Write down `cmd`, you should get one hit.
- Right click the search result and pick "Run as Administrator".
- Confirm the UAC prompt.
- In the console window switch to the users folder: `cd C:\users`
- Then create a symbolic link: `mklink /d Jason Jason.LAPTOP-8CBAIQSU`
- Once done, close the console window clicking on the X or using `exit`

You should then be able to use the path with Jason just add before. It's just an alias though, so funny delete the other folder.

---

As another solution, just create yet another user "Jason", which should note use the free/unused folder name.

Comment: how can I essentially clone my account so everything is exactly the same, but the user is named "Jason K," then delete Jason.LAPTOP-8CBAIQSU without any issue?

Comment: @user311302 There are tools for "migration" to a new PC. You could use them in your situation as well. It just copy your files by hand

Comment: I did that, but my search function broke afterwards, Microsoft tried clean installing, it flopped, and I had to reset the entire system.

Comment: @user311302 Windows has to create a new search index when you create a new user. It's completely bitmap for the search to appear broken for a while.